# Putting ellipsis (...) after certain number of character in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am reading educational data from facebook and showing it to my page directly. I find some string too long so i want to put ... after certain number of character in angularjs.

ex

```
jeevan sadhana english medium high school 08
```

to

```
jeevan sadha..
```

Comment: http://html5hub.com/ellipse-my-text/

Comment: why not with css? This is a good example: https://codepen.io/bmarshall511/pen/xxZBQPz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two possible solutions.

- Using pure CSS, use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` along with `overflow: hidden;`. Obviously, your element will have to be fixed width.
- You can use an Angular module such as [angular-truncate](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-truncate).

Answer (score 3):

Create filter in angular code.

Working http://jsfiddle.net/tUyyx/

Use filter code give in fiddle.

Then filter your content like :

```
{{ name | truncate : 25}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add ellipses after n number of lines then we can do this using Jquery.dotdot plugin
Check this link [Adding ellipses after n-bumber of lines in AngularJs](http://angularguru.blogspot.in/2015/01/adding-ellipses-after-n-bumber-of-lines.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
maxLength = 10;
str = str.length > maxLength ? str.substr(0, maxLength) + '...' : str;
```

Comment: I don't know man. Sure, this works. But first, you need to write some unnecessary JavaScript and second, you lose the original string completely.

Comment: Oh yes, it is definately destructive in that regard. In terms of unnecessary JS, I beg to differ on that point (you'd probably put it as a `$scope` variable though), because it could be reused throughout the scope of the controller and made dynamic if one were to turn this piece of code into a filter and pass the length into said filter. That way, you wouldn't loose the original string. However, should one want to do that, angular-truncate is probably the best bet as suggested by Zopieux.

Answer (score 0):

I used these three css stylings and it worked for me:

`text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;`

Also ensure that the width is fixed (in px or %age).